# array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array on sidefilter

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

[image]

---

i am on trouble on one issue. in sidebar filter feature, when i click on checkbox it will shown properly list.but when i unchecked checkbox it will shown "array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array" this error showing while inspect element.
when i click on checkbox it will generate this url "http://abc.local/genre-tags/?id%5B%5D=31"  .
and when i unchecked checkbox it will shown url "http://abc.local/genre-tags/" with error.
following are controller and js code.

```
public function genresFilter ()
    {
        $sortBy = Input::get('sortBy', 'id');
        $dir    = Input::get('direction', 'desc');

        $orderBy = [
                        'tracks'=>[   'order_by'=>$sortBy, 'direction'=>$dir ]
                    ];

        $id = Input::get('id');

        $category = Category::where('slug','music-genre')->first();

        $tag = Tag::with('tracks','elements')->where('category_id', $category->id)->whereIn('id', $id)->get();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($tag->toArray());
        die();
        
        $this->layout->content = View::make('public.tags.genres', compact('tag'));
    }


//Sidebar Filter Genre Tracks
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.genreTag').on('change', function (e)
    {
        
        $('input.filter-playlist, .popularGenreTag, .mood-emotion, .production-type, .vocals, .all-tracks, .last-year, .last-month, .last-week, .last-day').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.prop('checked', false);
            $this.parent().find('> div').removeClass('chk-checked').addClass('chk-unchecked');
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        id = [];

        $('.genreTag:checked').each(function()
        {
            id.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });

        $.get("/genre-tags/", {id: id}, function(data)
        {
            hideLoader();
            refreshedPage = $(data);
            newDemo = refreshedPage.find(".libraryWrapper, .albumWrapper, .composersWrapper, .albumsListWrapper, .albumsWrapper, .accountWrapper, .distributionsWrapper, .PaymentsWrapper, .contactWrapper, .contractsWrapper, .toolsWrapper, .blogWrapper, .pageWrapper, .cartWrapper, .pageWrapper").html();

            $('.libraryWrapper, .albumsWrapper, .albumWrapper, .composersWrapper, .albumsListWrapper, .accountWrapper, .distributionsWrapper, .PaymentsWrapper, .contactWrapper, .contractsWrapper, .toolsWrapper, .blogWrapper, .pageWrapper, .cartWrapper, .pageWrapper').html(newDemo);
            activatePlayer()
            initTrackInfo();
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
Route::get('genre-tags/', ['as' => 'tag.popular-genres', 'uses' => 'SideFilterController@genresFilter']);

//checkbox blade file

<li class="lib">
            <label><input class="genreTag"  id="{{ $genreTag->id}}" type="checkbox" name="" value="{{ $genreTag->name }}">{{{ $genreTag->name }}} ({{count(json_decode($genreTag->elements, true))+ count(json_decode($genreTag->tracks, true))}}) </label>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem in your controller:
you have whereIn query that need to pass array on 2nd args. but your id is null that why it give error like that. try to change code to below will work.

```
public function genresFilter ()
    {
        $sortBy = Input::get('sortBy', 'id');
        $dir    = Input::get('direction', 'desc');

        $orderBy = [
                        'tracks'=>[   'order_by'=>$sortBy, 'direction'=>$dir ]
                    ];

        $id = Input::get('id');

        // check if id is not array, then give empty array
        if(!is_array($id)) $id = [];

        $category = Category::where('slug','music-genre')->first();

        $tag = Tag::with('tracks','elements')->where('category_id', $category->id)->whereIn('id', $id)->get();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($tag->toArray());
        die();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('public.tags.genres', compact('tag'));
    }
```

## solution 2

```
public function genresFilter ()
    {
        $sortBy = Input::get('sortBy', 'id');
        $dir    = Input::get('direction', 'desc');

        $orderBy = [
                        'tracks'=>[   'order_by'=>$sortBy, 'direction'=>$dir ]
                    ];

        $id = Input::get('id');

        $category = Category::where('slug','music-genre')->first();

        $tag = Tag::with('tracks','elements')->where('category_id', $category->id);
        
        // if id is not null and and array then we do filter
        if($id != null && is_array($id)) {
           $tag->whereIn('id', $id);
        }

        $tag->get();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($tag->toArray());
        die();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('public.tags.genres', compact('tag'));
    }
```

Comment: @iAmGroot great it help

Comment: hi @sok hai .... on live give me this error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `tags` where `category_id` = 1 and `id` in ())"
type: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"" can you help me.

Comment: @iAmGroot if not. I updated solution 2 you can try. cuz we are in different time zone that why i just see it